# How many registers in custom VM?

Tags: c++, vm-implementation

I'm designing a custom VM and am curious about how many registers I should use. Initially, I had 255, but I'm a little concerned about backing 255 pointers (a whole KB) on to the stack or heap every time I call a function, when most of them won't even be used. How many registers should I use?

Comment: Why do you think you need to save all registers at function call?  Usually they are classified in 4 classes: global, caller saved, callee saved and scratch.  Only caller saved and callee saved have to be saved, and only if they are live at call point (for caller saved) or used by the function (for callee saved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I made a stupid on this one. Turns out that I already had a vector of registers to optimize access to the stack, which I totally forgot about. Instead of duping them, I just set the registers in the state to be a reference to the stack's registers. Now all I need to do is specialize pushing to push straight to a register, and problem solved in a nice efficient fashion. These registers will also never need backing, since there's nothing function-dependent about them, and they'll grow in perfect accordance with my stack. It had just never occurred to me that I could push values into them without pushing an equivalent value into the stack.

The absolutely hideous template mess this is turning into for simple design concepts though is making me extremely unhappy. Want to buy: static if and variadic templates.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into [register windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_window), which are a way of reducing the number of "active" registers available at any one time, while still keeping a large number of registers in core.

Having said that, you may find that using a stack-based architecture is more convenient. Some major virtual machines intended to be implemented in software (JVM, CLR, Python, etc) use a stack architecture. It's certainly easier to write a compiler for a stack rather than an artificially restricted set of registers.

Comment: AFAIK the Parrot VM is register based.  Those are rumored to be more optimizable, but for a first implementation, I'd also go to the stack based architecture.

Comment: I'm not so sure about "most". Especially if you look at the more modern ones: Lua recently switched from stack-based to register-based, Parrot is register-based, Dalvik (the VM for Android) is register-based, BESEN (the only existing implementation of ECMAScript 5) is register-based, at least one other JavaScript VM is register-based (Nitro, I think? I'm not sure which). And a couple of smaller ones: tinyrb is register-based, RubyGoLightly is register-based, Potion is register-based. The tinypy Python VM is register-based.

Comment: @AProgrammer: thanks for the info about [Parrot](http://docs.parrot.org/parrot/latest/html/docs/intro.pod.html), I've removed that from the list.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: that's interesting. I wonder whether those decisions have been made for performance reasons?

Comment: Dalvik did it for power efficiency, I believe. Lua, Parrot and Nitro/SquirrelFish did it for performance. Potion, tinyrb and tinypy are based on Lua (so, they basically did it because Lua did it) and RubyGoLightly is a Go port of tinyrb, so *it* does it because tinyrb does, which does it because Lua does it. BESEN was written by a guy from the demoscene, who is used to hack CPU registers by hand, maybe he was just trying to transfer his knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

This generally depends on how many you think you'll need. I question 255 registers' usefulness in practical applications.

The last register machine I built was aimed at supporting a small programming language, and when mapping things out, I looked at the types of applications, the design methodologies I wanted to guide people to use, balancing all that with performance concerns when designing the register file.

It's not something that can easily be answered without more details, but if you stop and think about what it is you're trying to do, and balance it all out with whatever aspects you find important, you'll come to a conclusion you can live with, and that probably makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever number of registers you choose, you are probably going to have way too many for most subroutines and way too few for a few subroutines. (This is just a guess. However, considering how many things in programming follow a Power Law Distribution – incoming references to objects, modules, classes, outgoing references from objects, modules, classes, cyclomatic complexity of subroutines, NPath complexity of subroutines, SLOC length of subroutines, lifetime of objects, size of objects – it is only reasonable to assume that the same is true for the number of registers for a subroutine, especially if you consider that there is probably a correlation between complexity/length and number of registers.)

The Parrot VM has found quite a simple way out of this conundrum: they have an *infinite* number of registers. Obviously, those registers aren't stored in an infinite array, rather they lazily materialize just enough registers for any single subroutine. That way, they never run out of registers, and they never waste any space.